# Why does Magento have only three flat tables

Tags: magento

Why does Magetno have three flat tables? What specifically three (not two, not four)

There's three for `catalog_category_flat`

```
catalog_category_flat_store_1
catalog_category_flat_store_2
catalog_category_flat_store_3
```

and three for `catalog_product_flat`

```
catalog_product_flat_1
catalog_product_flat_2
catalog_product_flat_3
```

Why?

Comment: it depends on how many store you have in your site ( we have three store ) so we have three flat tables

Answer (score 2):

Magento's structure is Website > Store > Store View

So those stores that Jeeten is talking about are actually Store Views. You can see them in admin under System > Manage stores or in the database in table core_store.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify what a few other the other commenters/answerers are saying.

Magento can, famously, host multiple "stores" in a single installation.  It does this by having different store views.  Many Magento product and category features are configurable **per store view**.  In a non-flat Magento system, this is achieved via the EAV tables and storing multiple values indexed by different store IDs (oversimplification)

So, this means Magento needs a single flat table for **each store view**.  In your installation (and with the sample data) this means three tables since there's three store views.